# bundle settings page on iOS 9 not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, bundle

I'm new in IOS. Problaby i'm missing some concept. I've followed [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) for creating a bundle setting page.

The settings page is created and I can see 4 settings that i've created in the settings file... ok.

I'm trying to get this values when app launch with this code when app didfinishlaunchwithoptions:

```
//Settings:
let standardUserDefaults : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
print(standardUserDefaults.boolForKey("Push"))
print(standardUserDefaults.stringForKey("Idioma"))
```

I don't get the right configuration values... Push is enabled but I always get false, and nil in Idioma...

Update: 
I followed [this instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217540/returning-the-value-of-a-settings-bundle-switch-in-swift-xcode-6) I've generated a plist file only to store defaults values and know I get the defaults values but I continue missing some concept because I want to know if any default setting is changed outside my app in the settings app of the Device. I've tested to uncheck Push value in settings of device and I still get the default value in my app... How my app knows when a default value has been changed in settings?

```
var myDict: NSDictionary?
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SettingsDefaults", ofType: "plist") {
        myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    }
    if let dict = myDict {
        print(dict["Push"])
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(dict as! [String : AnyObject])
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the save code, I mean set value to NSUserDefaults code

Comment: yes i've updated the topic with this info. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected for me, Please ensure you set values prior to call.

```
    let standardUserDefaults : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    standardUserDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "Push")
    standardUserDefaults.setValue("Idioma Value", forKey: "Idioma")

    print(standardUserDefaults.boolForKey("Push"))
    print(standardUserDefaults.stringForKey("Idioma"))
```

Output

```
true
Optional("Idioma Value")
```

Even in second run if I commented the value settings it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

My update note was not correct. RegisterDefaults and Synchronize works ok I was not checking correctly the value. I'm able to retrieve the changed value outside the app... Solved!